# How to show the bootstrap popover from the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-popover

I have a button that opens a bootstrap popover. This is the markup.

```
 <HeaderStyle Width="6%"></HeaderStyle>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="button1" data-toggle="popover" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Button1" />
      </ItemTemplate>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    content: $('#testDiv')
  });
```

The aim is to display the bootstrap popover from the code behind/ server side code. This is what I tried from the code behind which did not work.

C#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "popoverscript", "$('#testDiv').popover('show'); ", true);
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like code to show `popover` not executed because jQuery library may not already loaded or not in `ready` state when attempting to call `popover('show')` function in `RegisterStartupScript` method. Try wrapping that function call inside `document.ready` block:

```
string script = "$(function() { $('#testDiv').popover('show'); });"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "popoverscript", script, true);
```

**Note:** Also make sure that `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(...)` definition already wrapped inside `document.ready` block if `popover` still not showing up.

Similar issues:

[Show popover from code behind](https://forums.asp.net/t/1961462.aspx?show%20popover%20from%20code%20behind)

[bootstrap popover from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122975/bootstrap-popover-from-code-behind?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I completely agree with your view on it. We got the issue resolved. The content inside the jquery (popover) wasn't in the ready state/ wasn't initialized like you mentioned. My colleague [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7898069/jbizzle)@JBizzle came up with the solution. I will post the solution on the next comment.

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "popoverscript", "$('#" + button.ClientID + "').popover({ html: true, content: $('#actionButtonDiv'), container: 'body', trigger: 'focus', placement: 'left'});", true);                                                                         
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "show", "$('#" + button.ClientID + "').popover('show');", true);`

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the solution we found just a bit:

It was a timing issue. We were trying to initialize the popovers in JavaScript. We had put this:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    content: $('#testDiv')
  });
```

inside of a call to `Sys.Application.add_load()`. The problem was that when we went to show the popover from the server, the popovers weren't initialized yet, because anything on the client will execute *after* the server is done. The solution was to move both the initialization and the call to show inside of the server side button click event handler to make sure they were initialized and then shown in the proper order.

In the button event, C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "popoverscript", "$('#" + 
button.ClientID + "').popover({ html: true, content: $('#actionButtonDiv'), 
container: 'body', trigger: 'focus', placement: 'left'});", true); 

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "show", "$('#" + button.ClientID 
+ "').popover('show');", true);
```